# Using Python's CSV library to print an array as a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I have a python list as such:

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

I am trying to get it into a csv format so I can load it into excel:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

Using this, I am trying to write the arary to a csv file:

```
with open('tables.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(each_table)
```

However, it prints out this:

```
[
[
'
a
'
,
...
...
```

So then I tried putting it into an array (again) and then printing it.

```
each_table_array=[each_table]
with open('tables.csv','w') as f:
        f.write(each_table_array)
```

Now when I open up the csv file, its a bunch of unknown characters, and when I load it into excel, I get a character for every cell.

Not too sure if it's me using the csv library wrong, or the array portion.

I just figured out that the table I am pulling data from has another table within one of its cells, this expands out and messes up the whole formatting

Comment: What you mean by table? where you have that nested list?

Comment: Or rather its a python list, ill edit it

Comment: What about iterating through the list and writing every char + a comma?

Comment: well, this is just an example.. not all the entires are one character long

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library for your job:

```
import csv
each_table = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
with open('tables.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in each_table:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: this still prints out every character on every line

Comment: I think the writerow prints it all out on every line for some reason

Comment: @user2883071, which python version are you using? I slightly updated the snippet above for a more complete example, and my `tables.csv` file has 3 lines, each line with 3 characters as expected. I tried it on both python 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: You can do `writerows` and save a line.

Comment: zzz I just figured out that the table I am pulling data from has another table within one of its cells, this expands out and messes up the whole formatting. Also the table I am pulling from has hyperlinks, and these show up as duplicate cells

Answer (score 2):

As a more flexible and pythonic way use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id2) module for dealing with `csv` files Note that as you are in python 2 you need the method `newline=''` * in your `open` function . then you can use `csv.writer` to open you csv file for write:

```
import csv
with open('file_name.csv', 'w',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerows(main_list)
```

---

<sub>From python wiki: If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own ([universal](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) newline handling.</sub>

Comment: When I use this method, the `wb` throws an error: `TypeError: 'str' doe snot support the buffer interface`

Comment: @user2883071 Sorry i missed that you are in python3 , you need `w`

Comment: @DSM I just do that :)

Comment: You can do `writerows` and save a line.

Comment: zzz I just figured out that the table I am pulling data from has another table within one of its cells, this expands out and messes up the whole formatting. Also the table I am pulling from has hyperlinks, and these show up as duplicate cells